# Scroll div horizontally instead of page, then scroll page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, autoscroll

it isn't a duplicate as I've read the others question but everyone assume that the scroll is vertical, while i need this for horizontal scroll. 
What i'm trying to do is to scroll a div, placed somewhere in a page, when it reach the center of the screen or it is almost visible, then when it end its scroll i need to continue the page scrolll.

Actually i have a "slider" like this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/704on8dj/)

Actually, I can get an advise when the element is visible on the page after scrolling, but I don't know how to disable vertical scroll, scroll my div, and then scroll page again. The important thing is that the div scroll how much i continue the scrolling (intended with mouse, keyboard and maybe touch, it will be awesome)

```
function testInView($el){
var wTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var wBot = wTop + $(window).height();
var eTop = $el.offset().top;
var eBot = eTop + $el.height()+50;
return ((eBot <= wBot) && (eTop >= wTop));
}
function setInView(){
$(".slider-wrapper").each(function(){
    var $zis = $(this);
    $zis.removeClass("inview");
    if(testInView($zis)){
       alert("eccolo");   
    }
});
}
$(document).scroll(function(){
    setInView();
});
$(document).resize(function(){
    setInView();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInView();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable vertical scrolling then just set overflow-y: hidden on body element

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: i want to do that but i want to scroll the div when i block the page scroll, and i have to scroll the div instead of scrolling page when it is visible

Comment: If you want to scroll the div instead of page then hide the scroll on body and set scroll on div. Use overflow-x and overflow-y property to control scroll on x and y axis.

Comment: yes but the div isn't full page, it isn't also full width, so i have to scroll it also if i'm above the page